# What are those plastic clips delivered with my new bike?

Tags: bike-setup

I bought a new bike, online. It's a cube travel SLT, with belt drive, hydraulic brakes, alfine 11 hub.

In the box there were 2 of those plastic clips thingies, taken in the picture next to a set of hex keys for scale:
[image: plastic clip thingies]

I have absolutely no clue what they could be used for, and google is not my friend here. What can/should I do with them?

Comment: ...or the exact same piece: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/65901/what-is-this-tool

Comment: ... or that one: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/63152/random-piece-of-plastic thanks! Closed as duplicate.